# Partly Transparent Image Carousel

Tags: javascript, html, css, carousel

Right now I'm trying to make a Pokedex type thing for a project I'm working on. It works as intended except for now feature that I'd like to add. I want it so that it doesn't show the whole carousel throughout the page. I want it so that you have the main middle element, one 50% transparent element above, two 50% transparent elements below, and have the rest disappeared out. I was trying to get it to work myself, but the best I could accomplish was disappearing everything except the main middle element. Help would be greatly appreciated here.

**CSS**

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    background-image: url("../.img/pokedex/pokedex.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50%;
    background-size: 775px;
}

a, a:visited, a:active {
    color: inherit;
}

.sprite {
    display: block;
    margin-right: 310px;
    position: absolute;
}

.pkmname {
    display: block;
    margin-left: 225px;
    position: absolute;
}

.carousel {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    padding: 130px 0;
    margin-left: 340px;
    margin-top: 248px;
}

.carousel__scene {
    position: relative;
    width: 510px;
    height: 460px;
    max-width: 95vw;
    padding-top: 60px;
    perspective: 100px;
    /*overflow: hidden;*/
}

.carousel__controls {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 190px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.previous-button, .next-button {
    margin: 5px 0;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    font-family: monospace;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 2rem;
    border: 3px solid goldenrod;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #444;
}

.previous-button:focus, .next-button:focus {
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: 0 0 6px 3px goldenrod;
}

#prev, #next {
    margin-right: 50px;
}

.carousel__list {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translateZ(-288px);
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: transform 1s;
    list-style: none;
    counter-reset: list-counter;
}

.carousel__cell {
    position: absolute;
    width: 400px;
    height: 140px;
    max-width: calc(95vw - 20px);
    left: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    transition: transform 1s, opacity 1s;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    counter-increment: list-counter;
    background-image: url("../.img/pokedex/unknown.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}

.carousel__cell:not(.selected) {
    opacity: 50%;
}
    
    

.carousel__cell:before {
    content: counter(list-counter);
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px black;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
}

.carousel__cell.selected {
    color: goldenrod;
    border-color: goldenrod;
    border-width: 5px;
    /*filter: none;*/
}

.carousel__cell.before {
    opacity: 100%;
}

.carousel__cell.after {
    opacity: 50%;
}

.carousel__cell.hide {
    opacity: 0%;
}

.carousel__cell.selected::before {
    color: goldenrod;
}

.carousel__cell:nth-child(0) { transform: rotateX(0deg) translateZ(288px); }
.carousel__cell:nth-child(1) { transform: rotateX(40deg) translateZ(288px); }
.carousel__cell:nth-child(2) { transform: rotateX(80deg) translateZ(288px); }
.carousel__cell:nth-child(3) { transform: rotateX(120deg) translateZ(288px); }
.carousel__cell:nth-child(4) { transform: rotateX(160deg) translateZ(288px); }
.carousel__cell:nth-child(5) { transform: rotateX(200deg) translateZ(288px); }
.carousel__cell:nth-child(6) { transform: rotateX(240deg) translateZ(288px); }
.carousel__cell:nth-child(7) { transform: rotateX(280deg) translateZ(288px); }
.carousel__cell:nth-child(8) { transform: rotateX(320deg) translateZ(288px); }
```

**HTML**

```html
<div class="carousel">
            <div class="carousel__scene">
                <ol class="carousel__list">
                    <li class="carousel__cell" onClick="location.href='../../dexentries/0001-bulbasaur.html'"><img class="sprite" src="../../../.img/game-sprites/gen1/spr_rb-gb_001.png" alt="Bulbasaur"/><span class="pkmname">Bulbasaur</span></li>
                    <li class="carousel__cell" onClick="location.href='../../dexentries/0002-ivysaur.html'"><img class="sprite" src="../../../.img/game-sprites/gen1/spr_rb-gb_002.png" alt="Ivysaur"/><span class="pkmname">Ivysaur</span></li>
                    <li class="carousel__cell" onClick="location.href='../../dexentries/0003-venusaur.html'"><img class="sprite" src="../../../.img/game-sprites/gen1/spr_rb-gb_003.png" alt="Venusaur"/><span class="pkmname">Venusaur</span></li>
                    <li class="carousel__cell" onClick="location.href='../../dexentries/0004-charmander.html'"><img class="sprite" src="../../../.img/game-sprites/gen1/spr_rb-gb_004.png" alt="Charmander"/><span class="pkmname">Charmander</span></li>
                    <li class="carousel__cell" onClick="location.href='../../dexentries/0005-charmeleon.html'"><img class="sprite" src="../../../.img/game-sprites/gen1/spr_rb-gb_005.png" alt="Charmeleon"/><span class="pkmname">Charmeleon</span></li>
                    <li class="carousel__cell" onClick="location.href='../../dexentries/0006-charizard.html'"><img class="sprite" src="../../../.img/game-sprites/gen1/spr_rb-gb_006.png" alt="Charizard"/><span class="pkmname">Charizard</span></li>
                    <li class="carousel__cell" onClick="location.href='../../dexentries/0007-squirtle.html'"><img class="sprite" src="../../../.img/game-sprites/gen1/spr_rb-gb_007.png" alt="Squirtle"/><span class="pkmname">Squirtle</span></li>
                    <li class="carousel__cell" onClick="location.href='../../dexentries/0008-wartorle.html'"><img class="sprite" src="../../../.img/game-sprites/gen1/spr_rb-gb_008.png" alt="Wartortle"/><span class="pkmname">Wartortle</span></li>
                    <li class="carousel__cell" onClick="location.href='../../dexentries/0009-blastoise.html'"><img class="sprite" src="../../../.img/game-sprites/gen1/spr_rb-gb_009.png" alt="Blastoise"/><span class="pkmname">Blastoise</span></li>
                    <li class="carousel__cell" onClick="location.href='../../dexentries/0010-caterpie.html'"><img class="sprite" src="../../../.img/game-sprites/gen1/spr_rb-gb_010.png" alt="Caterpie"/><span class="pkmname">Caterpie</span></li>
                    <li class="carousel__cell" onClick="location.href='../../dexentries/0011-metapod.html'"><img class="sprite" src="../../../.img/game-sprites/gen1/spr_rb-gb_011.png" alt="Metapod"/><span class="pkmname">Metapod</span></li>
                    <li class="carousel__cell" onClick="location.href='../../dexentries/0012-butterfree.html'"><img class="sprite" src="../../../.img/game-sprites/gen1/spr_rb-gb_012.png" alt="Butterfree"/><span class="pkmname">Butterfree</span></li>
                </ol>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel__controls">
                <button class="previous-button" style="background: url('../../../.img/pokedex/prev.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center;" onClick="plusSlides(-1)"></button>
                <button class="next-button" style="background: url('../../../.img/pokedex/next.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center;" onClick="plusSlides(1)"></button>
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="../../../.js/pokedex.js"></script>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
// JavaScript Document

const carousel = document.querySelector('.carousel__list');
const cells = carousel.querySelectorAll('.carousel__cell');

const cellWidth = carousel.offsetWidth;
const cellHeight = carousel.offsetHeight;
const cellSize = cellHeight;
const cellCount = 151;

const radius = Math.round((cellSize / 2) / Math.tan(Math.PI / cellCount));
const theta = 360 / cellCount;

var selectedIndex = 0;

function rotateCarousel() {
    const angle = theta * selectedIndex * -1;
    carousel.style.transform = 'translateZ(' + -radius + 'px) ' + 'rotateX(' + -angle + 'deg)';
    
    const cellIndex = selectedIndex < 0 ? (cellCount - ((selectedIndex * -1) % cellCount)) : (selectedIndex % cellCount);
    
    const cells = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel__cell');
    cells.forEach((cell, index) => {
        if(cellIndex === index) {
            if(!cell.classList.contains('selected'))
                cell.classList.add('selected');
        }
        else {
            if(cell.classList.contains('selected')) {
                cell.classList.remove('selected');
            }
        }
    });
}

function selectPrev() {
    selectedIndex--;
    rotateCarousel();    
}

function selectNext() {
    selectedIndex++;
    rotateCarousel();    
}

var prevButton = document.querySelector('.previous-button');
prevButton.addEventListener('click', selectPrev);

var nextButton = document.querySelector('.next-button');
nextButton.addEventListener('click', selectNext);

function initCarousel() {    
    for(let i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
        const cell = cells[i];
        const cellAngle = theta * i;
        cell.style.transform = 'rotateX(' + -cellAngle + 'deg) translateZ(' + radius + 'px)';
    }
    rotateCarousel();
}

initCarousel();
```

Answer (score 1):

I went back and reworked what I was doing before so I actually figured it out. Here is the code I use so that I would have 2 items above and below the middle item. You can change the 2's to a different number if you want more or less items. Left 2 accounts for items below, right 2 accounts for items above.

```
function rotateCarousel() {
    const angle = theta * selectedIndex * -1;
    carousel.style.transform = 'translateZ(' + -radius + 'px) ' + 'rotateX(' + -angle + 'deg)';
    
    const cellIndex = selectedIndex < 0 ? (cellCount - ((selectedIndex * -1) % cellCount)) : (selectedIndex % cellCount);
    
    const cells = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel__cell');
    cells.forEach((cell, index) => {
        if(cellIndex === index) {
            if(!cell.classList.contains('selected'))
                cell.classList.add('selected');
        }
        else {
            if(cell.classList.contains('selected')) {
                cell.classList.remove('selected');
            }
        }
    });
    hide(cellIndex, cells);
}

function hide(cI, cells) {
    cells.forEach((cell, index) => {
        if(cI + 2 < index || cI - 2 > index) {
            if(!cell.classList.contains('hide'))
                cell.classList.add('hide');
        }
        else {
            if(cell.classList.contains('hide')) {
                cell.classList.remove('hide');
            }
        }
    });
}
```